# How to fill color Android Region?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can set fill color for particular Android path as follows.

```
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);

mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
mPaint.setColor(0xFF555555);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

After drawing paths on canvas I want to change the color on particular region. Is there a way to fill color using android `Regions` instead of `Paths`

Comment: `"on particular region"` what region do you mean?

Comment: @pskink Regions define within my app using paths like this `r.setPath(path, new Region((int) rectF.left, (int) rectF.top, (int) rectF.right, (int) rectF.bottom));` `r` is particular region.

Comment: so if you `"want to change the color"` you have to call `invalidate()` and draw your path again inside `onDraw` method

Comment: @pskink But now I have Regions. Not Paths.

Comment: read [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) API, here `Region`s can only be used for clipping, not for drawing anything